# C# Registry edit for icon seems not to work

Tags: c#, icons, regedit

I am using a file called .gfi for my program and decided a custom .ico file would look nice for this.

Using the following code I am successfully setting a reg key.

```
 RegistryKey key = Registry.ClassesRoot.CreateSubKey(".gfi");
            key.SetValue("DefaultIcon", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "icons\\gfi.ico");
            key.Close();
```

I can see they key when I go to regedit with the fowllowing

(Default) Value not set

DefaultIcon [path to icon file]

The path is correct and everything seems like it should work however the icon is  still not associated with the files.

Any help would be appreciated, thanks.

Comment: Did you try rebooting your machine?

Comment: I was thinking this, I was hoping the regedit should work straight away.

Comment: SHChangeNotify() can be used to inform the shell an association has changed without the need for a reboot

Comment: I was using this Alex to no avail, furthermore the reboot didn't work either.

Answer (score 1):

I know it has been a long time since this question was posted, but if anyone faces this problem, what you need to do is to add the index for the icon file, at the end of the string

this:

```
key.SetValue("DefaultIcon", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "icons\\gfi.ico,0");
```

instead of this:

```
key.SetValue("DefaultIcon", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + "icons\\gfi.ico");
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Registry.SetValue("DefaultIcon", AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"\icons\gfi.ico");
```

Your code is correct. You won't see it working right away because Explorer should be updated. No need to restart computer, just restart Explorer. You will see that it works.